# Why do I get an error when adding a listener?

Tags: typescript, ionic5

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    function onSuccess(position) {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.speed = position.coords.speed;
        console.log(this.speed);
        document.getElementById("updater").innerHTML = ' ' + this.speed +" m/s"
    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.onSuccess, this.onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    framework = 'At exact boarding time';

    constructor(private pickerCtrl:PickerController, 
        private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

    async showPicker() {
        let opts: PickerOptions ={
            buttons: [
                {
                    text:'Done'
                }

            ],

            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'framework',
                    options: [
                        {text:'10 minutes before boarding time',value:0},
                        {text:'5 minutes before boarding time',value:1},
                        {text:'At exact boarding time',value:2},
                        {text:'5 minutes after boarding time',value:3},
                        {text:'10 minutes after boarding time',value:4}
                    ],
                    selectedIndex: 2,
                }
            ]
        }
        let picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);
        picker.present();
        picker.onDidDismiss().then(async data=>{
            let col = await picker.getColumn('framework');
            this.framework=col.options[col.selectedIndex].text
        })
    }
}
```

So, at the top, I placed the listener, which should activate the following function "onDeviceReady()" upon start up of the app. Now I am trying to update an html element.

The element is not updating however, am I approaching this correctly? I am new to typescript.

Comment: What does the error message say? Because your code, as posted (and fixed so it runs) [works fine.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=64#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgIgUwG4wmgSmgQwBMBPACgEpEBvAWAChEnEIEBnOAGzQDpO4A5mQBEYAlgEEocAE48BaLnAhT4SAO6yA1m0Tq0nTsIoBuBgF8GDIspABbNGCg9iRAKIZHUADIw2URzQZESJMbCDCUmEAGmQwdCwcfGISWOACTjY0UyA)

Comment: I believe it was just an issue because it was in the HomePage class...so I moved it outside of the class and no more errors. I will update the post to show what i mean

Comment: Cool typescript playground by the way, will be very useful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `this.onSuccess` to `.watchPosition`. But `onSuccess` here is a local variable, and not a property of the execution context (`this`).

That means `onSuccess` will never get called.

Leave off the `this.` to pass in the locally defined function as the success handler.

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  onSuccess,
  onError,
  {
    maximumAge: 3000,
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  }
);
```

I'm actually very surprised typescript didn't flag this as an error. I would double check to make sure you've set it up properly.

---

In fact everywhere you use `this` in `onSuccess` is just leaking to the global scope. Either create an an object or class that handle this and keeps state, or refactor this to now use `this` at all.

Comment: awesome! It is working. It now updates my html doc. One more question for you, do you know how I would update this position variable/html element every second?

Comment: That's a very different question, with a very different answer, that depends on different details than you've posted so far. So give it a go until you get stuck, and then come back and post a new question with new relevant details. Good luck!